# Rename file with multiple special characters in pure bash/php

Tags: php, regex, bash

Is there a way I could rename a file like "štupîd-(ƒ†le)-nÆmè.txt" to "tup-(le)-nm.txt" so all unsupported characters are removed in bash or php?

Comment: yes there is, did you bother to try anything?

Comment: I did and found nothing regarding filenames or bash. Did you bother to read my question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use a character class and define every thing except what you need by `^` in the beginning of character class:

```
/[^\w-().]/
```

#### [Online Demo](https://3v4l.org/hnUKm)

---

PHP code:

```
$str = 'štupîd-(ƒ†le)-nÆmè.txt';
echo preg_replace("[^\w-().]","",$str);
//=>tupd-(le)-nm.txt
```

Comment: Works great and thanks for introducing me to that site

Comment: @skillascii You are welcome ..! Also I introduced you as an example for all those people like you that ask and hide. You have to care about the answer(s) and pay attention about them. Keep in mind, people help you for free and they expect at least just a *thx*.

Answer (score 0):

With php:

```
$str = 'štupîd-(ƒ†le)-nÆmè.txt';
echo preg_replace('~[^[:ascii:]]+~u', '', $str);
```

*(since you deal with an UTF-8 encoded string, you need to use the u modifier, otherwise the regex engine will read your string byte by byte instead of character by character. This may cause unwanted match)*

or

```
echo iconv('UTF-8', 'ASCII//IGNORE', $str);
```

With bash:

```
iconv -c -f UTF-8 -t ASCII <(echo 'štupîd-(ƒ†le)-nÆmè.txt')
```

Comment: iconv works best. Thanks for the help :)

Comment: @Shafizadeh: You assume that the OP is waiting for an immediate answer, but it isn't always the case. Sometimes, people chooses an answer the next hour, day, week... (Some of my answers have been accepted after more than one year!)

Answer (score -1):

In php you can do it with preg_match

```
preg_replace('/[^A-Za-z0-9-.]/', '', $targetFileDirty);
```

The above will replace everything BUT letters, numbers and dot with nothing.